# Angular material fxlayoutgap giving inconsistent output (sometimes not working)

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-flex-layout

I am using Angular v6.0.3 with material v6.1.0 & flexLayout v6.0.0-beta.15, I have a strange problem, I get inconsistent behavior from the same angular html code (in dev build & prod build):

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px">
  <button mat-button matStepperPrevious class="btn  btn-primary gray">{{'Back' | translate}}</button>
  <button mat-button matStepperNext class="btn  btn-primary pull-right"
  [hidden]="..."
    (click)="...">
    {{'Next' | translate}}
  </button>
</div>
```

The above code will sometimes show the two buttons with the desired gap of 20 px between them & sometimes will show them without the gap (the two buttons touching each other)

This different behavior happens in the same build if I run it in multiple tabs, I can't see why this is happening at all.

The output html code in case of working correctly:

```
<div _ngcontent-c2="" fxlayout="row" fxlayoutgap="20px" ng-reflect-layout="row" ng-reflect-gap="20px" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;"
class="ng-star-inserted">
<button _ngcontent-c2="" class="btn  btn-primary gray" mat-button="" matstepperprevious="" type="button" style="margin-right: 20px;">Back</button>
<button _ngcontent-c2="" class="btn  btn-primary pull-right" mat-button="" matsteppernext="" type="submit">
Next </button>
```

In the other case when there is no gap:

```
<div _ngcontent-c2="" fxlayout="row" fxlayoutgap="20px" ng-reflect-layout="row" ng-reflect-gap="20px" style="flex-direction: row; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;"
    class="ng-star-inserted">
    <button _ngcontent-c2="" class="btn  btn-primary gray" mat-button="" matstepperprevious="" type="button" style="">Back</button>
    <button _ngcontent-c2="" class="btn  btn-primary pull-right" mat-button="" matsteppernext="" type="submit">
    Next </button>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did anyone face a similar issue for inconsistent output of fxlayoutgap , sometimes working and sometimes not working ?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone else, the problem seems to be related to the field having a `[hidden]` attribute, when I replaced the hidden attribute with having the item in a `*ngIf` div the fxlayoutgap seems to work as expected.

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px">
  <button mat-button matStepperPrevious class="btn  btn-primary gray">{{'Back' | translate}}</button>
  <button mat-button matStepperNext class="btn  btn-primary pull-right"
  [hidden]="..."
    (click)="...">
    {{'Next' | translate}}
  </button>
</div>
```

Now the new code that is working is like this:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px">
  <button mat-button matStepperPrevious class="btn  btn-primary gray">{{'Back' | translate}}</button>
<div *ngIf="...">
  <button mat-button matStepperNext class="btn  btn-primary pull-right"
    (click)="...">
    {{'Next' | translate}}
  </button>
</div>
</div>
```